# How do you get windows media player to work in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, video

My final project in Fundamentals of Programming requires a video component and we haven't gotten to inserting a video yet. I found instructions for embedding Windows Media Player, but I'm having no luck playing files with it. I've tried compressing files into low bitrate WMV, and it complains about the file extension not matching (files play fine externally) and using a youtube link, which gives me no error, but the player says it's loading the media, then just stops and does nothing.

My current activation code is:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = txtVariable.Text;
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
```

And I'm setting up the video to be played as

```
txtVariable.Text = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHjpOzsQ9YI";
```

Does anyone have any clues on what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried everything on this page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503797/how-to-control-media-player-using-script-or-code?rq=1

Comment: I actually JUST got a local file to play. I want this to be highly mobile though, and still have no luck with the youtube linking, which would be the preferred method due to pathing and space constraints.

Comment: Is it actually possible to get a youtube link to work in that fashion? I've been looking at links and answers but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: I'm going to guess, for anyone looking to this for help, that the youtube video link is working, but it's not in a format that WMP can play. It's just a wild guess, but I'm thinking the best solution is just for me to switch to a flash object then figure out how to do external controls on it to manipulate it through code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to play a youtube video because the URL does not refer to the "actual" video. This URL redirects you to a web page that contains the video. The URL should refer only to a video for example, "webpage.com\Videos\video.mp4".